# Pre Populate Core Data By Copying .sqlite File From Documents

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have read that this works, but I can't get it to. I want to pre populate Core Data. I ran my project so it would create the sqlite file. I copied that to my desktop and then prepopulated it using the command line, sqlite3. I ran queries to make sure it was populated correctly. So now I re-add it to my project. No matter what I do, though, it won't fetch the data.

I got it to work ONCE. I re-copied the sqlite file from my project's document folder after running it in the simulator. I then populated this new sqlite file. I put it back in my project and I got the contents to display.

I think the problem is the Z_METADATA table. This table has a Z_UUID attribute. I think the only time it worked was when the simulator's UUID and the sqlite's Z_UUID attribute were the same.

I went into ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and deleted the contents of the DerivedData folder. So now my simulator will have a different UUID when I run it. I did this and now the contents of the sqlite file will not display. This is why I think the Z_METADATA table is the problem. The Z_METADATA's UUID and my simulator's UUID are not the same so for some reason it can't use it?

All the articles about pre populating Core Data this way I found are old, around 2009, so I don't think this was a problem then. So can I use this method of copying the sqlite file, using the command line to pre populate it, then re-adding it to the project? Does anyone have a current way to prepopulate Core Data?

So the error is that my `NSFetchedResultsController` is returning a count of 0 objects. I got it to return all the data the one time I mentioned above.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same DataModels?What is the error, that occures?

Comment: Yes. I created the data model, ran the app, then copied the sqlite file, so it was the same model. The error is just that my `NSFetchedResultsController` is returning 0 objects. Like I said I got it to return all the objects in the database one time.

Comment: Check the [WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), in particular session 227 and the related sample code (which is also on the videos website). It's about using Core Data with iCloud, but even if you aren't doing iCloud, it's worth looking at their approach to prepopulating the database. Instead of copying files around, you can have a persistent store coordinator backed by two separate stores: the read/write one in the Documents directory, and a read-only one in the app bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW1),

> **Important** Although Core Data supports SQLite as a store type, the store format—like those of the other native Core Data stores—is private. You cannot create a SQLite database using native SQLite API and use it directly with Core Data (nor should you manipulate an existing Core Data SQLite store using native SQLite API). If you have an existing SQLite database, you need to import it into a Core Data store (see “Efficiently Importing Data”).

While I'm sure someone has reverse-engineered the Core Data sqlite format, Apple does not provide any documentation, and it is likely to change across across major OS releases.

Write a command-line app that uses Core Data to do your import.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check this out Monday and let you know if I can get it imported. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks command line app worked. So people know... Create a new Mac 'Command Line Tool' project. I had a tab delimited text file that I parsed then used Core Data API to populate Core Data. I then copied the sqlite file that was created into my iOS project. In the iOS project just be sure to change the name of the sqlite file to the one you imported in AppDelegate and make sure the Data Model is the same.

Comment: I did it on iOS 4.0 and it works until now with iOS 6.0 without changing it. But you are right, it is not supposed to work like that. I created an empty store and filled it external with an sql tool, then core data loaded the pre filled with all its content. If you want to make it manually (which I also did, created tables etc) then you only need the UUID from an empty file created from an model that is build like the sqlite. Until now I could not figure out how to generate this UUID outside of core data.